# cooling a hot pan while cooking

Tags: pan, heat

My question is about cooling a pan while cooking. I come to the issue when I'm making a dish and it tells me to have a pan at medium-high to sear meat. Then it tells me to remove the item and saute garlic. When I do that the garlic always burns, so obviously it's asking me to cool the pan down. How do I do that without splashing water or something else? Do I just leave it off the burner for a minute or 2 while it cools down and then go for the garlic?

Comment: Please add some punctuation to your question. It's very difficult to read as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just remove the pan from the heat for a couple of minutes.

Don't forget to lower the burner heat.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the pan from the heat to a cool burner.
2. Lower your burner temperature.
3. Remove your protein.
4. Pop a knob of butter and/or a drizzle of cooking olive oil, etc and toss in your garlic.
5. Sautee in the residual pan heat for a few seconds or a minute until it calms down and return to the burner.

Then what I like to do, when the garlic is ready, is to deglaze with a splash or two of stock or wine and scrape up all the fond and reduce the liquid by at least half and maybe wisk in a little pat of butter at the end for an amazing garlicy pan sauce you can drizzle over your meat.